# sanic - How to specify required JSON?

Tags: python, python-3.5, sanic

I would like to specify the required JSON for a controller `get`/`post` methods in order for it to show in SwaggerUI.

For example, I want `request.json` to look like this:

```
{
  'key1': <int>,
  'key2': <string>
}
```

I initialize SwaggerUI like this:

```
from sanic_openapi import swagger_blueprint, openapi_blueprint

app = Sanic(__name__)

# Set up SwaggerUI
app.blueprint(openapi_blueprint)
app.blueprint(swagger_blueprint)
```

How can I make both keys show up in `parameters`?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is `sanic_openapi.doc.consumes` decorator for decorating view functions to document their input. This naming of the decorator function follows from the [OpenAPI specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md).

Here is one way to apply it:

```
@app.post('/recording_test')
@doc.summary('Tests a recording')
@doc.consumes({'key1': str, 'key2': int}, location='body')
async def create_recording_test(request):
    ...
```

You can model your input using a class.

```
class RecordingTest:
    key1 = str
    key2 = int
```

Use the modeled input above in the following manner

```
@app.post('/recording_test')
@doc.summary('Tests a recording')
@doc.consumes(RecordingTest, location='body')
async def create_recording_test(request):
    ...
```

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did but it doesn't work. Is it because I use app.add_route from run.py? Or is it because I use `get` method inside a resource class?

Comment: I'm not sure I can map out your code this way. Can you edit your question with the code you're referring to?

Comment: Sure, but I'll give adding these blueprints after I add the routes a try before that. Right now I first add these blueprints and then call `app.add_route`, I'll just try the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You did not see this params in swagger because your get method is on class.
Sanic-openapi and Sanic-swagger does not support class based views yet. :(